# Need help authorizing index action with Pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, pundit

I'm using Pundit and Devise on my app. My index action looks like this in my wikis_controller:

```
  def index
    @wikis = current_user.wikis
    authorize @wikis
  end
```

I'm trying to prevent un-signed-in users to access this index action but `@wikis` is getting set to `undefined` since there is no user logged in. In return, it's not authorizing.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can authorize against the model instead of an object.

The code

```
authorize Wiki
```

will trigger the index? action in your pundit policy without the user object. In addition, you can use a scope to filter the data on a another level https://github.com/varvet/pundit#scopes.